# Working with Sharepoint 2010 Calendar RSS Feed

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-calendar, rss

I am working with a developer to create a native mobile application (iOS and Android) and I am almost completely ignorant of SP 2010.

We have found the RSS feed for the calendar and we were successful in using AJAX to grab the feed and return it as JSON.

As an example, here is what is returned:

```
 [Object, Object]0: Objectauthor: "Mietlinski, Anabel"categories: Array[0]content: "<div><b>Start Time:</b> 2/18/2015 10:00 AM</div>↵<div><b>End Time:</b> 2/18/2015 2:00 PM</div>↵<div><b>Description:</b> <div></div></div>"contentSnippet: "Start Time: 2/18/2015 10:00 AM↵End Time: 2/18/2015 2:00 PM↵Description: "link: "http://campus.kellerisd.net/schools/bwe-126/Lists/Campus Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=1196"publishedDate: "Wed, 11 Feb 2015 11:42:30 -0800"title: "2nd Grade Field Trip Symphony Performance"__proto__: Object1: Objectauthor: "Mietlinski, Anabel"categories: Array[0]content: "<div><b>Start Time:</b> 2/16/2015 8:00 AM</div>↵<div><b>End Time:</b> 2/16/2015 3:00 PM</div>↵<div><b>Description:</b> <div></div></div>"contentSnippet: "Start Time: 2/16/2015 8:00 AM↵End Time: 2/16/2015 3:00 PM↵Description: "link: "http://campus.kellerisd.net/schools/bwe-126/Lists/Campus Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=1195"publishedDate: "Wed, 11 Feb 2015 11:37:05 -0800"title: "No School - Holiday"__proto__: Objectlength: 2__proto__: Array[0]
```

We are able to work with this however what we are trying to access the Start and End Date of each event in order to use this data in the device calendar.  It seems that based on the view we have that the Start Date and End Date are lumped together as part of Description node rather being directly accessible via their own entry.  The RSS looks like this:

```xml
  <description><![CDATA[<div><b>Start Time:</b> 2/18/2015 10:00 AM</div><div><b>EndTime:</b> 2/18/2015 2:00 PM</div><div><b>Description:</b> <div></div></div>]]></description>
```

So is there a way to change the feed where these two data points are directly accessible and able to be parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waldek has a fantastic article on customizing a content query web part to create an RSS feed, http://blog.mastykarz.nl/creating-rss-feeds-sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part/

I had seen an article around that showed how to create an aspx page with a DVWP that rendered content in a more standard RSS feed. I wish I could find it too.

The short of it it, regardless if you use json or xml, the default rss feed renders the date in that fashion.

Edit, it was [Andrey that had the article I was thinking of](https://web.archive.org/web/20150301071719/http://markeev.com/Articles/sharepoint-blog-rss.aspx). Using a technique like this, you can roll your own feed and get the output in the format you wish.